# Increasing the load capacity on Gateway

Tags: c++, linux, select, udp, udpclient

I am trying to send **10,000** XML requests continuously in `while()` loop from **Client** to the **Gateway**(which acts as a server to this client) over **UDP** transmission. The Gateway implements `select()` function call to monitor the **read_fds**. In Gateway, the `struct timeval` values that i am passing to `select()` are:

```
tv.tv_sec = 5;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
```

> each XML request is of **1500** bytes and both client and Gateway are
>   coded in C++ and the binaries run on Linux (RHEL 5)

**There are two cases:**

**case 1:**
At Client side, if i send **10,000** XML requests continuously in `while()` loop and implement a delay of **500** micro seconds using `usleep()` between each requests, the Gateway accepts all the **10,000** requests, parses it and logs the requests into a .log file.

**case 2:**
At Client side, if i send **10,000** XML requests continuously in `while()` loop without any delay, the Gateway is accepting only **2,600** requests, parses it and logs the requests into a .log file.

**Question:**
How can i increase the no. of requests accepted by the Gateway, without implementing a **delay** at the Client side? Also please tell me what happens to the remaining **7,400** requests from Client in **case 2**, are they lost?

Comment: Try `epoll` with edge-triggered option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server side receive buffer isn't read fast enough, the remaining messages are indeed lost: that is how UDP works.

If you just need to handle a burst of 10000 messages (and not cope with sustained traffic), you could just increase the buffer size: `sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=nnnnnnn`.

Alternatively start profiling where the time is spent in your server read loop. You could e.g. remove all the parsing and logging as a test, and just count the number of messages you receive: If that helps you reach a number closer to 10000, then it would imply the parsing and logging is too slow for that loop.

Another thing to check would be to look at which messages you are losing: if you get constant message-loss even in the early messages (e.g. in the first hundred messages) then that would imply that something else on the way cannot handle messages that fast -- the receive buffer on the server is not to blame in that case.

Comment: sysctl -p | grep mem
net.core.rmem_max = 41943040
net.core.wmem_max = 41943040
net.core.rmem_default = 4194304
net.core.wmem_default = 4194304

Comment: i tried to check my system parameters, but the max size of 8 digits is already set for the buffer, and as you mentioned like 7 digits, now i am in doubt as whats the max size limit, also want to know can i do any more tuning wrt above parameter values as they already seem to be set at max values.

Comment: _Alternatively start profiling where the time is spent in your while loop._ sorry but, which while loop are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to say "while loop": was trying to refer to the server loop that handles the receive buffer. I improved that part of the answer. That said, your `net.core.rmem_max` value is already pretty big: it should definitely be enough for 10000 messages.